# How can I integrate WebORB with IIS7?

Tags: iis, rtmp

Basically I need to be able to run RTMP through tunnel. How do I integrate WebORB with IIS7?

Answer (score 0):

install weborb and run the folowing command: 
%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd migrate config "Default Web Site/"